# Android - Validate a subscription offline

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscription

My application provides functionality that is unlockable via a subscription. Users will quite often want to use the functionality at times where there is no Internet connection available. This presents the problem of checking weather a user has a valid subscription before allowing them access to the functionality while there is no connectivity. Can anyone offer some methodology/best practises/Examples of how to approach this use-case?

Cheers.

Comment: Save the subscription details locally when there is internet connection. Use the local db details to check if the subscription is valid or not.

Comment: xbox one comes to mind... but you could use their original idea.

Comment: Haha, Unfortunately I need to pay yearly for the the data I provide in the unlocked functionality, so in order for me to provide the service, the user does too :)